# Separate the Jobs search results from Q&A search results in the custom Google Search

Tags: feature-request, search, stackexchange.com, jobs

When I do a search for [rollbar](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=rollbar) for the entirety of the Stack Exchange network, I get results for both ordinary content, and advertised jobs, and they look fairly similar. For example, the ad says that it's "Stack Overflow", and nothing in the URL indicates that it's advertising. The only difference is in the icon/thumbnail.

[image: Screenshot]

They should either be separate, or there should be more to indicate that a result is an ad, rather than ordinary content.

The Stack Overflow user generated post is [How prevent rollbar from reporting errors in the development environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19657288/how-prevent-rollbar-from-reporting-errors-in-the-development-environment) , while the Stack Overflow ad is https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/130330/entry-level-software-engineer-at-rollbar-rollbar

**Clarification:** I'm not complaining about the advertising provided by Google - that's clearly marked as advertising, and is easily ignored. I'm complaining about the "result" titled "Entry-Level Software Engineer at Rollbar at Rollbar - Stack Overflow".

Comment: That's not advertising. Jobs are integral part of Stack Overflow, same way that the questions and answers are. Advertising is for the external advertisement, or when Jobs is being advertised on the sidebar (internal advertisement) but not when it's in search results, IMO.

Answer (score 1):

Weeeellll actually these aren't technically *ads*. Rather, they're organic search results from Google as a result of Stack Overflow Jobs listings being publicly accessible. The only actual advertising we do for Jobs is in the sidebar on stackoverflow.com, serverfault.com, and a handful of other SE Network sites.

Comment: Do employers have to pay for Stack Overflow Jobs postings?

Comment: @Andrew pretty sure they have to pay, that's how SO makes money.